# Batch: Doing a whois command in a loop doesn't seem to work

Tags: batch-file

I can manually do a whois command, but when I try to make it iterate over a list of DNS addresses, it doesn't work. 
Code:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (dnsnames.txt) DO whois %%A > results.txt
```

Output for two addresses:

```
Whois v1.12 - Domain information lookup utility
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
Copyright (C) 2005-2014 Mark Russinovich

Connecting to COM.whois-servers.net...
Connecting to COM.whois-servers.net...
Connecting to whois.markmonitor.com...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get this message: (when I change `>` to `>>`)

```
TERMS OF USE: You are not authorized to access or query our Whois
database through the use of electronic processes that are high-volume and
automated except ...
```

Comment: That's probably my problem.